# How to find elements with negative margins?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on large application and I am 100% sure there is an element with a negative margin, which is collapsing my content?

How would one go about finding all elements with negative margins using JavaScript?

Comment: Why don't you just use the devtools inspector?

Comment: Ok. How about opening the CSS file in editor then searching for `margin: -` or `margin:-`

Comment: So what? You can extend the search to include an entire directory. I don't know what IDE you are using but with something like Notepad++ this is an easy task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do this

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = elems.length; i--;) {
    var m = window.getComputedStyle(elems[i],null).getPropertyValue("margin");
    console.log(m)
}
```

From here you can either study the log or break down the variables into `margin.left`, etc., and check if any is less than 0.

Comment: what is `startElem`?

Comment: Looks promising but it only logs the values, how would one identify the element?

Comment: @Aziz Either by set a background color on it, or read out its outer HTML, or ... many choices